# The same method with webrequest works in one program but not in another

Tags: c#, timeout, webrequest

I have a c# console program calling a library method with webrequest that works fine, but when I call the same library method from another program (an mvc site) it just hangs.  It never times out even though I give it a timeout value.

```
console app:
   console project
   bitly project

mvc site
   web server project
   bitly project
```

I've verified it works fine with the identical values from the console app, but just sits there with the web code.

```
var url = $"https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token={apikey}&longUrl={WebUtility.UrlEncode(longUrl)}";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
try
{
    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        response.Timeout = 30000
        var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        var jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
        var statusCode = jsonResponse["status_code"].Value<int>();
        if (statusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
        ...
    }
}
```

This is in a bitly.library project I created.  The library is only using a newtonsoft nuget package.  The calling programs both use the same version of the system.net.http if that is a question.

I've verified that both programs end up with the same url going out.

When I call it from the console app, the GetResponseStream() call comes back right away with the data.  When I call it from the webhook (this is for an sms system), the GetResponseStream() hangs forever.

I've tried this on two different machines as well.

My only clue here is that the timeout never seems to work, making me think something is up with the webrequest library in the web server solution. But as it's not using a nuget package for either, I'm lost as what it could be.

Comment: Have you tried hitting the Url with a browser from the web server?  It may simply not have access.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and verify the working and non working both have the same headers in 1st request.  If not make non working look exactly like working.  The default headers are different in Net from other methods.

Comment: I think you are experiencing a deadlock. Can you provide us the code from your console/web applications where you are calling this bitly library?

Comment: Did using `GetResponse` (no `Async`) make the problem stop? Same for `ReadToEnd` (do both).

Comment: Both programs show the same url, and both work from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching the code to use HttpClient instead of WebRequest, and the problem cleared up.

I'm not sure why WebRequest acts like this, but it's working fine now.